Debug `ros::NodeHandle nh` received a SIGSTOP while using gdb in qtcreator
Note: Firstly, my code can be compiled successfully. If I just run the code, it is ok. But if I run in Debug mode, error merges in the line ros::NodeHandle node. specifically, the code stop after the function _M_initialize() in /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h（I tried c++ 9, and it didn't work）. It seems that it cannot initialize the memory?
The same problem is happen to my notebook too(ubuntu 20.04). But in my another computer with ubuntu 16.04, the code works in debug mode.
I have spent more than a week on this problem, but I has not find uesful solution. I appreciate that if someone can help to solve this problem. Please.
I found the reason that after I excute ros::init(argc, argv, "mpccontrol"), there is no rosnode initilized by waching rosnode list.
But I still have no idea how to solve this issue. Why ros::init() is normally excuted, but it init a rosnode in Debug mode.
The info of my computer:
Ubuntu 20.04 (I also tried buntu 22.04 and 18.04, and the same problem)
qt creator 5.9.4 (I also tried 5.12, did not work)
gdb 9.2 (I also tried gdb 8.2)
gcc 6.4.0
cmake 3.16.3
My test code is as follows:
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "mpccontrol");
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    while (ros::ok()) {
        cout << "******************* publish successfully ************" << endl;
        count ++;
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}


my .pro:
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt


CONFIG( debug|release){
OBJECTS_DIR = .obj
TARGET = rosTest
}

# #==================== config ros ==================
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/ros/noetic/include \
                ./message    \

DEPENDPATH += /opt/ros/noetic/include  \
    ./message   \

#LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib   \
#        -L/usr/local/lib64\

LIBS += -L/opt/ros/noetic/lib -lroscpp -lrospack \
        -lpthread -lrosconsole -lrosconsole_log4cxx \
        -lrosconsole_backend_interface -lxmlrpcpp \
        -lroscpp_serialization -lrostime  -lcpp_common \
        -lroslib -lyaml-cpp -lkdl_conversions

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    NodeHandleTest.cpp

HEADERS += \
    NodeHandleTest.h

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO

I have tried to change the system version: ubuntu 18.04/ 20.04/ 22.04. It seems that this problem has no relationship with the system version.
I have tried to change gdb version, and it does not work.
I have tried to change the qt creator version.

My guess (nothing more than that) is that you have some kind of version conflict in the C++ standard library. For example you are using the header files from one version of the standard library but linking with a different version of the standard library.

Probably the way to progress with this is to eliminate possible suspects. For example forget about Qt, forget about ROS, can you compile and run a simple C++ program that uses (indirectly) the header file /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h. If not then you know Qt and ROS are not to blame. Any C++ program that uses std::map would be a good test (I think).

The way not to progress is to thrash around trying different things just hoping something will work. If anything that is going to make matters worse, and even if you do get something working you won't know if it was just cooincidence or if you have really solved the problem.

@john actually, I tried to change the version of GCC and G++, but it still did not work. It cannot pass ros::NodeHandle nh; in debug mode. But it works fine in release mode.

The version of gcc and g++ are not what I talked about. The version of the C++ standard library was my concern. When you compile code you include headers, when you link code you link libraries. Because these are different files in different locations it's perfectly possible to include one version of the header files, and link with a different version of the library files. This usually leads to a crash somewhere in the standard library code, which is exactly what you are seeing.

@john Hi, john. I have found the reason, but I still have no idea to solve it. The reason is in Debug mode, ros::init(argc, argv, "nodename") did not init a rosnode. In my another computer, I can receive a rosnode by rosnode list after ros::init(argc, argv, "nodename") was excuted. Do you have a idea how to solve this issue?

I have no experience with the 3rd party libraries you are using. As I said earlier, my advice would be to try and eliminate those libraries from the issue you are facing. I think it's likely that your issue is not caused by ros or qt. But either way, the method you need to follow is to break the problem down as much as possible by eliminating what you can and seeing if you still get similar problems.

@john this issue most likely is related to ROS. Jason mentions using different Ubuntu distros so they're running different versions of ROS; some wildly different, some on unsupported platforms, and some EOL. OP needs to provide what distros they're trying to run on.

@john, and BTbles Thank you for providing soluctions. I have solved this problem by changing my qt creator version to 5.12.12. This qt version is valid for all my three computer.

I have solved this problem by changing my qt creator version to 5.12.12 (download: https://www.qt.io/offline-installers).
Thank John and BTables again.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
